# Notation: $P(x)$ iff $x$ has property $P$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, notation, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

In set theory (for example), people write $P(x)$ to indicate that $x$ has property $P$. What is the meaning of this "expression" formally? Is $P$ a predicate (a Boolean-valued function on some set [what set?]) that returns $\top$ iff $x$ has property $P$? If this is the case, then shouldn't one write $P(x)=\top$ instead of $P(x)$?

Comment: In first-order logic, $P(x)$ is a *predicate* symbol, and we use the part "(x)" to express the fact that it is *unary*, i.e. it has only one argument place. A *predicate* symbol is used to denote a "property". We can use e.g. $R(x,y)$ to denote a *binary relation*.

Comment: In first-order logic (aka: predicate logic) we can use $P(x)$ to express the linguistic expression : "$x \text { is a Penguin}$".

Comment: $P$ is a *predicate symbol* of theory of birds. And this theory doesn't talks about sets of birds. When we use, for example, set theory to build a **model** of theory of birds - we find a set corresponding to predicate $P$. However, $P(x)$ is not a formula of set theory itself. It's important to distinguish theory (that can use symbol $P$ in formulas, but knows nothing about underlying sets) and meta theory (that knows about sets, but can't use symbol $P$ as predicate symbol).

Answer (score 2):

No, if $P(x)$ is some formula of set theory (like $\exists y \forall z\colon z \in x \rightarrow z \in y$), then it's not a function. Also, $\top$ isn't in alphabet of set theory, and only terms (expressions value of which is set) can appear at left (or right) of symbol $=$.

If you use set theory to build a model of another theory (even of set theory itself) - it becomes another story. Then formula of this modeled theory can be considered as denoting some subset of model. For example, if we want to model Peano arithmetic, we can take some set as support of model (for example, set $\omega$), and define $+_{PA}$ and $\cdot_{PA}$ as functions on it, and $\leqslant_{PA}$ and $=_{PA}$ as subsets of $\omega \times \omega$. But "for PA" it will not be sets or functions - it will be just symbols.

Comment: But sometimes one considers sets like $\{x\in X:x\text{ is a penguin}\}$, which is expressed by $\{x\in X: P(x)\}$. In this case $P(x)$ is not a formula.

Comment: If "to be a penguin" can be expressed in terms of set theory - then it is (probably not written explicitly). Otherwise it's not a formula of set theory.